# Remove buttons line above cell in Jupyter in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am trying to remove this annoying line above every cell when sing Jupyter in VSCode:

[image]

It just clutters the whole notebook unnecessarily and I use shortcuts for everything anyways. I want that entire line above the cell gone so it looks just like when you open a Jupyter notebook in the browser. Does anyone know how to get rid of this? Thank you!

Comment: it seems VSCode problem (or rather "feature")  not directly Jupyter or Python. Probably authors of `VSC` decided that this line can be useful for users. And you would have to ask authors of `VSC` to add options which remove it.

Comment: @furas Hmm interesting. I have posted an issue to the VSCode github repo. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is recommended that you use "[Visual Studio Code Insiders](https://code.visualstudio.com/insiders/)", its Jupyter notebook interface is more suitable for your needs:

[image]

Comment: Do you know when this will be in the stable version?

Comment: @TheMAAAN -Once this feature works well in VSCode, I will update my answer and remind you. In addition, you could also follow it: [Hover Documentation Pop up does not work after VSCode 1.52 update](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/4218).

Answer (score 3):

This appears to now be possible to change in settings.

In Settings, search: `@tag:notebookLayout`

Under `Notebook: Cell Toolbar Location` change `jupyter-notebook` to `hidden`.

[image]