# How can I move the cell toolbar in a Jupyter Notebook cell in VS Code to the right or left of the cell?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Somehow I changed the side of my "cell toolbar". It was usually on the right and I'm used to using it there.

Does anyone know how to move the cell toolbar to the right again?

[image]

If you take a look at this official VS Code tutorial the cell toolbar is on the right too.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/jupyter-support-py

Comment: Did you see [this answer that mentions `Notebook: Cell Toolbar Location`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69369598/8508004)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `notebook.cellToolbarLocation` setting. Like this in a [settings.json file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson):

```json
"notebook.cellToolbarLocation": {
    "default": "right", // or "left" if you want it on the left
}
```

The setting's description:

> Where the cell toolbar should be shown, or whether it should be hidden.

The default value is `"right"`, so if you just want to restore the default, check all your settings files to see if you changed it to `"left"` in any of them, and if so, delete those lines of JSON so that the default takes effect.